# jaxws exception/error handling

Tags: java, jax-ws

I try to build wsdl client for `jre5` with `JAX-WS RI 2.1.3` its my first expirience. I genereted classes with `wsdl2java` tool from `cxf` and wrote wrapper class around client looks like:

```
public class RequestHelper {
    private DataLoadService service = new DataLoadService();
    private DataLoadServiceSoap client;
    private static String token;

    //....my constructor....

    public void sendData(data){
     try{
       if (tokenIsExpired()){
          renewToken();
       }
       client.sendData(data, this.token);
      }catch(SOAPFaultException e){
           //...work with e
      }
    }
}
```

I can't understand how i can process exception in `sendData` method. 
I mean, for example, in HTTP we have `status codes`, we can read status code and decide which type of error we get from server and how we want process them.
In my case i have problem with token expired time. Sometimes `sendData` request goes to the server for a long time. And the token is no longer valid when the request is already on the server then i get exception with text message "Token expired". And i want catch this type of exception separately, somthing like this:

```
public class RequestHelper {
private DataLoadService service = new DataLoadService();
private DataLoadServiceSoap client;
private static String token;

//....my constructor....

    public void sendData(data){
     try{
         if (tokenIsExpired()){
            renewToken();
         }
         client.sendData(data, this.token);
       }catch(SOAPFaultException e){
       //...work with e
       }catch(TokenExpiredException e){
         renewToken();
         client.sendData(data, this.token);
       }
    }
}
```

How i can achieve this with `JAX-WS RI 2.1.3` library?

UPD:

```
} catch (SOAPFaultException e) {
 SOAPFault f = e.getFault();
 f.getFaultString() //yes here we have error description with "Token"
                    //but with locals dependency, this is not safe handle exception by this value
 f.getFaultCode() //here simply string "soap:Receiver", do not know how i can recognize only "token exceptions"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Find out what is been returned as part of the SOAPFaultException from the server. If the Exception contains the error message then we can write something like below. note: Error code will be the best way to handle this.

```
    try{
         if (tokenIsExpired()){
            renewToken();
         }
         client.sendData(data, this.token);
       }catch(SOAPFaultException e){
           if(e.getFault().getFaultString().equalsIgnoreCase("Token expired") ) {
               renewToken();
               client.sendData(data, this.token);
           }
           ......
       }
```

Another way is to have custom SOAP exception thrown from the sever with error code and error message and handle that in the code

Comment: please see my update, i do not have access to server side code. thanks for advice